# A pageBlockSection component must be contained within a pageBlock component

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to upload data file stored in my system. But i am getting this error on VF Page
**Error:A pageBlockSection component must be contained within a pageBlock component**

VF Code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select a file to be uploaded" collapsible="false"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="panel_Upload">
    <apex:form id="form_Upload">
        <apex:inputFile id="file_File" value="{!fileBody}" fileName="{!FileName}"/>
            <br/>
        <apex:commandButton id="button_Upload" value="Upload" action="{!processUpload}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
<br/>
```

Comment: Is the code that you pasted, enclosed in an `apex:pageBlock`? Please could you attach the whole excerpt?

Comment: @lavanya I also doubt same thing.Pageblocksection must be within Pageblock.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code using `<apex:pageBlock>`

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select a file to be uploaded" collapsible="false"/>

    <apex:outputPanel id="panel_Upload">
        <apex:form id="form_Upload">
            <apex:inputFile id="file_File" value="{!fileBody}" fileName="{!FileName}"/>
                <br/>
            <apex:commandButton id="button_Upload" value="Upload" action="{!processUpload}" />
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

For more information look at the [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm)